# htacess add text in url for some pages

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have some custom urls like http://example.com/cars/blabla and http://example.com/cars/blabla2 and i need add /portal to all pages that have /cars/.

Result must be http://example.com/portal/cars/blabla. I can't change base url to http://examaple.com/portal becouse /portal must apply not to all pages. 
So i think it must be done via htaccess file, but i have no idea how.

Thanks.

Comment: Question is not at all clear. Can you try to explain clearly with examples.

Comment: content in adress http://example.com/cars/blabla must shows by adress http://example.com/portal/cars/blabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(cars/.+)$ /portal/$1 [L,NC]
```